# How to find the hashing algorithm used to hash passwords?

Tags: hashsum, passwd

I have the working password and can see the hash (/etc/passwd). How do I find the hashing algorithm used to hash the password, without manually trying different algorithms until I find a match?

Comment: What Unix variant are you using?

Comment: I'm very surprised you can see a hash in `/etc/passwd`. I thought all Unix/Linux variants had moved to a split with `/etc/shadow` years ago. (I know such systems still support hashes in `passwd` but I know of no utilities that put them there any more. An embedded system, perhaps?

Comment: It's OpenWrt Backfire 10.03. Hashes are still stored in `/etc/passwd` here. This however does not change the matter of the question. Does it?

Comment: Just for the record: The BSDs have two Berkeley DB files, roaima.  It's still split, but it's not `/etc/shadow` and they have no file by that name.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is documented in [`crypt(3)`’s manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html), which you can find *via* [`shadow(5)`’s manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shadow.5.html), or [`passwd(5)`’s](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5@@shadow-utils.html). Those links are appropriate for modern Linux-based systems; the description there is:

> If *salt* is a character string starting with the characters "$*id*$"
>          followed by a string optionally terminated by "$", then the result
>          has the form:
>
> ```
> $id$salt$encrypted
> ```
>
> *id* identifies the encryption method used instead of DES and this then
>          determines how the rest of the password string is interpreted.  The
>          following values of id are supported:
>
> ```
> ID  | Method
> ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> 1   | MD5
> 2a  | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some
>     | Linux distributions)
> 5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
> 6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
> ```

Blowfish, also known as `bcrypt`, is also identified by prefixes `2`, `2b`, `2x`, and `2y` (see [PassLib’s documentation](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html)).

So if a hashed password is stored in the above format, you can find the algorithm used by looking at the *id*; otherwise it’s `crypt`’s default DES algorithm (with a 13-character hash), or “big” `crypt`’s DES (extended to support 128-character passwords, with hashes up to 178 characters in length), or BSDI extended DES (with a `_` prefix followed by a 19-character hash).

Some distributions use [libxcrypt](https://github.com/besser82/libxcrypt/) which supports and [documents](https://github.com/besser82/libxcrypt/blob/develop/doc/crypt.5) quite a few more methods:

- `y`: yescrypt
- `gy`: gost-yescrypt
- `7`: scrypt
- `sha1`: sha1crypt
- `md5`: SunMD5

Other platforms support other algorithms, so check the `crypt` manpage there. For example, [OpenBSD’s `crypt(3)`](https://man.openbsd.org/crypt.3) only supports Blowfish, which it identifies using the *id* “2b”.

Comment: DES based passwords are BTW always 13 characters long and consist of alphanumerical characters as well as `.` and `/`. The first 2 characters is the salt and the other 11 is a hash value (sort of). And it is the only one of the algorithms supported by `crypt` which is so weak that you cannot compensate for it by choosing a stronger password.

Comment: If anyone else is wondering why their local `man 3 crypt` looks nothing like this, it’s likely because `libxcrypt` replaces that man page with its own, which doesn’t have this valuable contents (but a less concise equivalent is to be found in `man 5 crypt`). `libxcrypt` is *de facto* installed on many(?) systems (as it’s required by SystemD, OpenSSH, CUPS, Python…).