# How to calculate the password length if the user already exists in Linux?

Tags: linux, password

How to calculate the password length if the user which already exists in Linux?
I only know the encrypted password for that user in another file `/etc/shadow`. Can I calculate the password length from the value in this file?

Are there any other ways to solve this?

Comment: generally you cannot, since that is intentionally hidden

Comment: complexity of password is defined in misceleanous files in /etc/pam.d

Comment: Could  you say about the specific point of thinking?

Answer (score 5):

The passwords are stored hashed, i.e. the actual passwords are never stored but a cryptographic checksum is stored in `/etc/shadow`. You can't compute the length of a string from a cryptographic hash of that string. Doing so would be equivalent of breaking/cracking the cryptographic hashing algorithm.

What you want to do is similar to finding the length of a file from its MD5 checksum.  This can not be done.

Tangentially related:

- [How to find the hashing algorithm used to hash passwords?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430141/how-to-find-the-hashing-algorithm-used-to-hash-passwords)

Comment: Is there any other way to solve it? I mean in Other OS mechanisms