# How to know if password in /etc/shadow is hashed with SHA or MD?

Tags: ubuntu, password, hashsum, shadow

I want to know my `/etc/shadow` password hash if its SHA or MD or something else. From what I read, it is related to the `$` sign, but I don't have any dollar signs.

Im using Ubuntu 16

Example:

```
user:0.7QYSH8yshtus8d:18233:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the hashing algorithm used to hash passwords?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430141/how-to-find-the-hashing-algorithm-used-to-hash-passwords)

Comment: Is that an actual example or did you modify it? Because without the `$n$` markers, it should be ye olde DES hash, but the length doesn't seem to match it (yours is 16 characters, and `crypt()` returns a string of 13 characters). I also wonder how a three-year old Ubuntu would end up using DES. What do you have in `/etc/pam.d/common-password`, on the line with `pam_unix.so`? Or in `/etc/login.defs` with `ENCRYPT_METHOD`?

Comment: @ilkkachu that's not DES and DES hasn't been used for eons. The glibc `crypt(3)` functions does DES just for compat with dummy old games and such. The OP may be testing the waters, for all that I could guess ;-)

Comment: @mosvy, well, like I said, the length doesn't match. Otherwise it looks like it could be a DES hash. Of course it hasn't been used for eons in any sensible system, but the support is still out there. At least `chpasswd` can be coerced to use it... That's why I wondered how they managed to get that hash.

Comment: What's more DES can be written into `/etc/passwd` (instead of `shadow`). Support is definitely out there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `shadow(5)` manual on Ubuntu refers to the `crypt(3)` manual.  The `crypt(3)` manual says that the default password encryption algorithm is [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard).

It goes on to say that the `glibc2` library function also supports MD5 and at least SHA-256 and SHA-512, but that an entry in `/etc/shadow` for a password encrypted by one of these algorithms would look like `$1$salt$encrypted` (for MD5), `$5$salt$encrypted` (for SHA-256), or `$6$salt$encrypted` (for SHA-512), where each `$` is a literal `$` character, where `salt` is a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) of up to 16 characters, and where `encrypted` is the actual hash.

Since your encrypted password does not follow that pattern, I'm assuming that it's encrypted using the default DES algorithm.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to mention that the DES password hash algorithm will only store passwords of up to 8 characters, and will ignore the rest. So if the actual password is longer than that, just getting the first 8 characters right will be enough. Even that alone might be reason enough to switch to another, more modern password hashing scheme. In Ubuntu, the password hash to use when changing a password is usually specified by options to `pam_unix.so` PAM module in `/etc/pam.d/common-password`.