# openssl -- is there a salt limit?

Tags: openssl

was reading another post and the example of using a salt was:

```
openssl passwd -crypt -salt foo bar
foXrpAKGo3142
```

but if I change the salt to

```
openssl passwd -crypt -salt foo111 bar, I still get
foXrpAKGo3142
```

is there a limit on the salt length?  It seems to be 2 chars.

thx!

Answer (score 2):

With the `crypt` algorithm, the salt limit [is 12 bits](https://manpages.debian.org/crypt.5). Other algorithms support longer salts; with `openssl passwd`, you should use `-5` or `-6`.

See also [How to find the hashing algorithm used to hash passwords?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/430141/86440)

Answer (score 0):

The `-crypt` algorithm for `openssl passwd` is a legacy algorithm that should not be used anymore. [It can be brute-forced at moderate cost](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5204/can-des-based-hashed-password-be-recovered-if-salt-is-known). It's the [traditional DES-based `crypt()` password hashing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#Traditional_DES-based_scheme) which was introduced in [Seventh Edition Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_7_Unix) in 1979. It limits the salt to 2 printable ASCII characters, and the password to 8 printable ASCII characters. It has no practical value except for historical purposes or on extremely outdated (and insecure) systems.

Anyone using it in a code example either doesn't know what they're saying or doesn't care about giving good advice. If you see `openssl passwd -crypt` in an example of anything except very old, legacy usage, run away.

For password hashing, use, in order of preference:

- [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2), the official standard since 2015.
- [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt), which is memory-hard.
- [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or the similar Unix algorithms [SHA-crypt](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt), which are CPU-hard but not memory-hard.

OpenSSL only implements the Unix algorithms (`openssl passwd -5` or `openssl passwd -6`, with `-5` being slightly faster on 32-bit machines and `-6` on 64-bit machines).

None of these use a ridiculously small (by today's standards) salt.

See also [In 2018, what is the recommended hash to store passwords: bcrypt, scrypt, Argon2?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193351/in-2018-what-is-the-recommended-hash-to-store-passwords-bcrypt-scrypt-argon2) and [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords).