# Encrypted password with no linked algorithm

Tags: security, password, shadow

I was reading the shadow file structure explained [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/).

I was wondering what happens if, perhaps for some type of error or wrong manual changes, the $id field representing the hashing algorithm is missing.

The hash would be interpreted using a default system hashing algorithm? Or the account would be locked down for having no hashing algorithm associated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the has identifier is lost, the hash will be interpreted as coming from the DES `crypt` algorithm (the default). The real password won’t match, so the user will in effect be locked out from the account, but the account itself won’t be locked down — so for example root will be able to access it.

It may be possible to find a password which *will* hash to the stored hash, interpreted as a DES hash, but that will only be possible for users who have read access to the file containing the hashes.

See [How to find the hashing algorithm used to hash passwords?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/430141/86440) for details of the hash identification.