# Looking for a list of hash ids

Tags: security

To identify a hash it (mostly) has the format `$id$salt$hash$`, sometimes with some more parameters between `id` and `salt`.

Long ago I found a web page with a really large list of ids, but I forgot to bookmark (bummer). Google lists me sites with ids 1-6 only or a few more like SHA1 or y. Does anyone has a longer list? Are these ids possibly fixed in an RFC?

Comment: I know that shadow passwords in *nix are formatted like that. But if there is a better place for my question, please tell me where.

Comment: OP searches for a list of hash algorithm identifierts, not rainbow tables, something like this: https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html#mcf-identifiers

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430141/how-to-find-the-hashing-algorithm-used-to-hash-passwords

Comment: I already found the latter one, but here also the ids 1-6 only are listed whereas your former link has a lot more ids. Thanks a lot. But no, I'm not interested in rainbow tables.

Comment: If you read slightly further down the answer to the latter question, you’ll find values for ids after 6.

Comment: If I could only remember where I found that list. It was really long ... 
But yes, it answers my question partially.