# Cracking linux user hash with john doesnt work

Tags: linux, kali-linux

**"Error" message: No password hashes loaded"**

I can not crack any password hash with john, neither with dictonary attack nor with brute force, it says: "No password hashes loaded (see FAQ), i checked FAQ and cant find a mistake, where is my error in thinking

OS: Kali linux version: 2022.4 (Just as info because i read that different OS, and of course different versions use different hashing algorithms)

So i created a new user with a hash (i just created one as a test):

```
user:$y$j9T$nx6tHrvLJSyr630Qc5Svy0$xD2GizOYUiD/oQtq8j98xbe3FRlc6K0GqZ6I7UngjZ/:19272:0:99999:7:::
```

On many websites (also my script i have) i read that i first have to add the /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow together (that the x in /etc/passwd gets replaced with the hash) with the following command (and redirect the output to a new file):

```
sudo unshadow /etc/passwd /etc/shadow > myhash.hash
```

I created a wordlist which looks like this:

```
1234
2345
3456
6578
6789
7930
3452
3241
8959
3546
```

and saved it as wordlist.txt. So now i have myhash.hash and wordlist.txt and want to run a dictionary attack (same issue with brute force) and run

```
john --wordlist=/home/user/hash/wordlist.txt myhash.hash
```

(7930 is the correct password btw)

and the output is:

```
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/user/hash]
└─# john --wordlist=/home/user/hash/wordlist.txt myhash.hash
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)
```

BTW: My /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow has no problems, they are safe and not damaged, i checked them.

I went for google and read the FAQ:

```
Q: Why doesn't John load my password file? It says "No password hashes loaded", "No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)", or "No password hashes left to crack (see FAQ)".
A: Your password file taken from a Unix-like system might be shadowed. You need to get both /etc/passwd and the shadow file (typically /etc/shadow or /etc/master.passwd), and combine them into one file using "unshadow" (which is supplied with John). Please refer to EXAMPLES.
```

**SUMMARY:** I have checked my files where the cracked hashes are in, and there is nothing in there, i used "locate" command, so i definitely deleted all. It always tells me "No password hashes loaded", checked on 3 different KALI VMS(i know, debian based) and normal Debian VM. I tried the same method with brute force, it does't let me do it. I did it exactly as 4 other websites did it and it doesn't work for me. Where is my error in thinking?

Comment: Are you sure that "$y" hashes ("yescrypt" hashes) are supported by JTR?  They're not very common.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430143/168757

Comment: I just know that they are on every machine running kali, so i d be wondering, i already checked hashcat, which has manyyyy hash algorithms but yescrypt is not part of it. Thank you for your help